# Elegant and portable way to handle SNMP tables in Python

Tags: python, snmp, net-snmp, pysnmp

I have been searching a lot for this, but not found anything that fits my needs yet. I want an elegant way to work with SNMP tables in Python. I have looked at pysnmp and net-snmp python bindings.

At the moment I am working with net-snmp bindings, as it seems more easy to query data with, and it is already easily available on CentOS6 where the software will have to run (Python 2.6), but I would not mind installing pysnmp either.

What I want is any kind of object which I can hand over my important data of my table structure, such as table base OID, index OID and names and oids of the columns I am interested in. I would like to get a data structure back that makes it very easy to iterate over the rows, fetch lists of entries of any of the columns etc, all without having to bother with OIDs and stuff anymore, really abstracting all this away.

The purpose of this is that I want to use as little code as possible to query all data from a SNMP table and work with it, I would like to have all boiler plate code in a module so I can fetch and work with data of a SNMP table in just a few lines of code.

What would you suggest me to do? Writing my own abstraction based on pysnmp or netsnmp? Is there anything in pysnmp's High Level API that I might have missed? Maybe a python module that abstracts one of the above mentioned to make it more easy to access the data?

Would be very glad to hear your advices.

Comment: Standards such as RFC3416 define the approaches to perform "table traversal". You should check the library you use has something like those. If not, they are still quite easy to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Speaking of pysnmp, there are two components that may be of interest to you:

- [ObjectType/ObjectIdentity](http://pysnmp.sourceforge.net/docs/pysnmp-hlapi-tutorial.html#working-with-snmp-tables) classes representing MIB object and handling OID<->symbol<->index and value types matters
- High-level [API](http://pysnmp.sourceforge.net/docs/pysnmp-hlapi-tutorial.html#snmp-command-operations) operating over ObjectType instances

On top of these two components you could [read](http://pysnmp.sourceforge.net/examples/hlapi/asyncore/sync/manager/cmdgen/table-operations.html#fetch-table-row-by-composite-index)/[modify](http://pysnmp.sourceforge.net/examples/hlapi/asyncore/sync/manager/cmdgen/modifying-variables.html#coerce-value-to-set-to-mib-spec) MIB objects referring to them by their MIB names and symbolic indices e.g. knowing nothing about the OIDs being involved. The ObjectType class would transform values between their human-friendly representation and base SNMP types.

The pysnmp library would work on Python 2.6.